# ¿Por qué me da error 400 cuando uso onCompleted en useQuery de Apolo?

Tags: graphql, nextjs

Estoy usando Apolo para obtener datos de graphCMS, y me da este error en la consola del navegador cuando uso
la función `onCompleted`:

> POST
> [https://us-east-1.cdn.hygraph.com/content/[codigo](https://us-east-1.cdn.hygraph.com/content/%5Bcodigo) graphcms]jjjj/master
> 400 createHttpLink.js?903c:99

```
const PostWidget = ({ categories, slug }) => {
  const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([]);

  const {
    loading: lpostsim,
    error: errpostsim,
    data: datasim,
  } = useQuery(
    getSimilarPosts,
    {
      onCompleted({ data: datasim }) {
        setRelatedPosts(data.posts);
      },
    },
    {
      variables: {
        categories: categories,
        slug: slug,
      },
      skip: !slug, // no hay slug?? true: no hay. false: si hay. true: salta
    }
  );
```

Esta es la consulta:

```
export const getSimilarPosts = gql`
  query GetPostDetails($slug: String!, $categories: [String!]) {
    posts(
      where: {
        slug_not: $slug
        AND: { categories_some: { slug_in: $categories } }
      }
      last: 3
    ) {
      title
      featuredImage {
        url
      }
      createdAt
      slug
    }
  }
`;
```

Si comento `onCompleted` se quita el error.

También he usado `onCompleted` de esta forma:

```
{
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        setRelatedPosts(data.posts);
      },
    },
```

Y sigue el error. ¿Cómo me deshago del error, sin quitar la función `onCompleted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución: el problema radicaba en que estaba haciendo mal uso de la anidación de las llaves `{}`. En unas llaves llamaba la propiedad `onCompleted` y en la otra a *variables*. El código funciona sin error de esta manera:

```js
const {
    loading: lpostsim,
    error: errpostsim,
    data: datasim,
} = useQuery(getSimilarPosts, {
     onCompleted: (data) => {
      setRelatedPosts(data.posts);
    },
    variables: {
      first: POSTS_PER_PAGE,
      categories: categories,
      slug: slug,
    },
    skip: !slug, // no hay slug?? true: no hay. false: si hay. true: salta
    });
```

Nótese que tanto *variables* como `onCompleted` se encuentran dentro de las mismas llaves de *opciones* de querys de `useQuery`.